# change the get url before laravel 5.1 route intercepts it

Tags: url-rewriting, routes, laravel-5.1, pretty-print

After finally mastering crucial parts of Laravel I'm ready to refactor all of my procedural code.

I have one problem, some other program's use the following url's like this:

> http://my.domain.com/somecode.php?something=a&somethingelse=b

Now as I learned, laravel route looks like:

> http://my.domain.com/somecode/something/a/somethingelse/b

How should I intercept the old style of url in laravel or before the laravel route is called and translate it so the route can handle it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you will only be doing this with `GET` you could use middleware to solve your issue.

**Create the middleware**

`php artisan make:middleware RedirectIfOldUrl`

...or whatever you want to call it.

**Add the definition to your `app/Http/Kernel.php`**

add `\App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfOldUrl::class,` to the `$middleware` array (not the `$routeMiddleware`) array.

This will cause the middleware to be called on every request.

**Handle the request**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if (str_contains($request->getRequestUri(), '.php?')) {

        //Remove .php from the request url
        $url = str_replace('.php', '', $request->url());

        foreach ($request->input() as $key => $value) {

            $url .= "/{$key}/{$value}";
        }

        return redirect($url);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

The above is a very basic implementation or what you mentioned in your question. It is possible that you will need to tweak the logic for this to work exactly right for your application but it should point you in the right direction.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Looks like a solid solution, I will try and get back

Comment: This is a perfect solution, Can't upvote more then once, but would have done it in this situation.

Comment: Ross - could something similar be done to modify the request. I want to modify the url before it is handled by the router rather than redirect it... so /en/my-url and /es/my-url etc are all handled by the /my-url route

Comment: @Ben, IMO, If they're going to be handled by the same endpoint just have both routes point to that endpoint.

Comment: @RossWilson IS it possible to handle the request instead of redirecting. I now have an older terminal that can't handle the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to rewrite the path using this middleware in Laravel 6.2, and adding it to `app\Http\Kernel.php`:

```php
<?php
    
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
    
use Closure;
    
class Localize
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 4 ) === "/es/" || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === "/es") {
            $request->server->set('REQUEST_URI', substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 4));
            app()->setLocale('es');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

If you try to use: `$request->server->get('REQUEST_URI')` the set command won't work properly, I'm guessing the calling the get() results in some sort of caching.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It tries to find a route with the lang in it and ends up in a 404.

Comment: @JeremyBelolo Did you add the middleware to Kernal.php? `\App\Http\Middleware\Localize::class,`

Comment: Of course :) Probably a difference with Laravel 8...

Comment: @JeremyBelolo I did this in 6.2, althought there issue if you use a $request->server getter before the set(), I opened an issue for this but it was closed: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/32929#event-3363824169

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious now there is no legitimate way to do this.