# Allowing Double Slash in Route - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Version Laravel Framework 7.21.0

I am having issue to allow double slash in the url.

Success : http://example.com/api/v1/reference

NotFound Exception : http://example.com//api/v1/reference

How do i allow double slash in my url ?

I managed to allow multiple slash in the url in the previous Version of Laravel : 5.8.16

Comment: I think you should remove '/' from your `api.php` from `/api/v1/reference` to `api/v1/reference`

Answer (score 1):

You can add Middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware removeSlashes
```

and add it to $routeMiddleware under App/Http/Middleware

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
  'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
   ....
  'removeSlashes' => \App\Http\Middleware\RemoveSlashes::class,        
];
```

implement code to remove extra slash in RemoveSlashes::class

and call to middleware in your api.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => ['RemoveSlashes'....]], function () { 
    Route::GET(.....);

});
```

Comment: It does not work, as your prefix is not matched.
Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302687/change-the-get-url-before-laravel-5-1-route-intercepts-it for a solution to actually remove the double slashes